# Regexp to catch links not in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regexp in JavaScript to catch all links in a text, except ones inside anchor tags (both href attribute or inner text).

For example, the following should match:

```
http://google.com
```

However, nothing should match in the following:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Link</a>
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
```

I've found [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252866/regex-replace-all-url-s-that-are-not-anchored/7254397#7254397), but it requires lookbehind, which is not supported by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OhAuth's answer `(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[^"]*?(?=<|\s|$)` uses the fact that the actual link in anchor tag is followed by ("), meaning neither lookbehind nor its workarounds are neccesary.

EDIT:

Using only lookaheads, we can achieve something like this: `(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[^\"<]*?(?=\s|$|<\/[^a]>)`, which results in this: https://regex101.com/r/eR3mT4/1 , failing in an anchor title that contains link and aditional characters. That situation seems difficult for regex and lookbehinds wouldn't help.

Comment: no in ```<a href="http://www.website.com">http://website.com</a>``` I don't want match anything...I want match only in a simple link in text...if there is any anchor tag i don't want match anything inside href or inside anchor tag

Comment: Wrote an edit for most cases, using lookaheads. The link inside an anchor title with aditional characters is a difficult task for both lookbehinds, lookaheads and regex in general as there is no control whatsoever of what may or may not be before or after the possible link in the anchor title.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[^"]*?(?=<|\s|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603748/2943191

```
((https?|ftps?):\/\/[^"<\s]+)(?![^<>]*>|[^"]*?<\/a)
```